# Validação de CPF - Integration Services

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

estou importando uma base com CPFs para o meu DW porém preciso fazer validação de CPF dentro do SSIS.

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como posso fazer isso?

Obrigada!

---

edit:

Consegui resolver da forma que eu queria.

Utilizei o script component, peguei um código de validação em c#.

Ficou dessa forma
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você quer saber se um dado número obedece à regra de formação do CPF ou se este número, além de obedecer à regra de formação, esta cadastrado na base de dados da receita como um CPF válido?

Comment: Quero saber se ele é um CPF válido de acordo com a base da receita

Comment: Então você terá que consultar a base de dados da Receita Federal. A consulta à Situação Cadastral lhe dará esta informação. O que não sei é se existe algum tipo de web service grátis para isso.

Answer (score 1):

Pode utilizar uma função do SQL Server ?

```
/*
  Cristiano Martins Alves
  Para testar: SELECT DBO.CPF_VALIDO('16195473247')
*/
CREATE FUNCTION CPF_VALIDO(@CPF VARCHAR(11))
RETURNS CHAR(1)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @INDICE INT,
          @SOMA INT,
          @DIG1 INT,
          @DIG2 INT,
          @CPF_TEMP VARCHAR(11),
          @DIGITOS_IGUAIS CHAR(1),
          @RESULTADO CHAR(1)

  SET @RESULTADO = 'N'

  /*
      Verificando se os digitos são iguais
      A Principio CPF com todos o números iguais são Inválidos
      apesar de validar o Calculo do digito verificado
      EX: O CPF 00000000000 é inválido, mas pelo calculo
      Validaria
  */

  SET @CPF_TEMP = SUBSTRING(@CPF,1,1)

  SET @INDICE = 1
  SET @DIGITOS_IGUAIS = 'S'

  WHILE (@INDICE <= 11)
  BEGIN
    IF SUBSTRING(@CPF,@INDICE,1) <> @CPF_TEMP
      SET @DIGITOS_IGUAIS = 'N'
    SET @INDICE = @INDICE + 1
  END;

  --Caso os digitos não sejão todos iguais Começo o calculo do digitos
  IF @DIGITOS_IGUAIS = 'N' 
  BEGIN
    --Cálculo do 1º dígito
    SET @SOMA = 0
    SET @INDICE = 1
    WHILE (@INDICE <= 9)
    BEGIN
      SET @Soma = @Soma + CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(@CPF,@INDICE,1)) * (11 - @INDICE);
      SET @INDICE = @INDICE + 1
    END

    SET @DIG1 = 11 - (@SOMA % 11)

    IF @DIG1 > 9
      SET @DIG1 = 0;

    -- Cálculo do 2º dígito }
    SET @SOMA = 0
    SET @INDICE = 1
    WHILE (@INDICE <= 10)
    BEGIN
      SET @Soma = @Soma + CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(@CPF,@INDICE,1)) * (12 - @INDICE);
      SET @INDICE = @INDICE + 1
    END

    SET @DIG2 = 11 - (@SOMA % 11)

    IF @DIG2 > 9
      SET @DIG2 = 0;

    -- Validando
    IF (@DIG1 = SUBSTRING(@CPF,LEN(@CPF)-1,1)) AND (@DIG2 = SUBSTRING(@CPF,LEN(@CPF),1))
      SET @RESULTADO = 'S'
    ELSE
      SET @RESULTADO = 'N'
  END
  RETURN @RESULTADO
END
```

fonte: http://www.devmedia.com.br/funcao-para-validar-cpf-no-sql-server/2723

Comment: Na vdd, eu preciso usar algum componente que faça a validação. Como o conditional split, q ai os cpfs validos eu vou inserir na tabela e os inválidos eu vou gerar um output.

Comment: aí é só usar a função... não ?

Comment: Da forma que eu queria fazer achei melhor usar o script component

Comment: bacana, você conseguiu valida-lo tambem na base da receita ?

Comment: Eu usei um script em C# que valida faz a validação. Que por fim é a mesma lógica do seu script

Comment: No comentario da sua pergunta, você diz que valida pela base da receita, a validação do codigo que postei, é pelo digito verificador. Você consegue validar pela base da receita ? ou seja, saber se o CPF está ativo na receita federal ?

Comment: Quando eu disse que valido pela base da Receita é pra saber se é um CPF que realmente existe. Acho que rolou uma confusão nesse conceito. Saber se ele está ativo ou não, não era o meu objetivo.

Comment: Certo, porém só alertando que essa lógica do dígito verificador, apenas informa se o número tem o formato do CPF, ainda assim, pode ser que não exista, ok? rsrs boa sorte =]